# Angular test fails because Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular

I am creating some tests in Angular 4. I have a component that is using PrettyJsonCompont in order to show well formatted json to the user.

When I run ng test several of my component tests fail with the same message.

> Failed: Type PrettyJsonComponent is part of the declarations of 2
>   modules: PrettyJsonModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider
>   moving PrettyJsonComponent to a higher module that imports
>   PrettyJsonModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new
>   NgModule that exports and includes PrettyJsonComponent then import
>   that NgModule in PrettyJsonModule and DynamicTestModule.

Here is what my test looks like.

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {ContentItemModalComponent} from './content-item-modal.component';
import {DialogService} from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal';
import {ContentItemService} from '../services/content-item.service';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule} from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MainModel} from '../models/main-model';
import {PrettyJsonComponent, PrettyJsonModule} from 'angular2-prettyjson';

describe('ContentItemModalComponent', () => {
  let component: ContentItemModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContentItemModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
        FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
        HttpModule,
        PrettyJsonModule
      ],
      declarations: [ContentItemModalComponent, PrettyJsonComponent],
      providers: [
        DialogService,
        ContentItemService,
        MainModel
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContentItemModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem is that `configureTestingModule` creates a new Angular module. And you declare the component `PrettyJsonComponent` in it. But this component is already declared in the `PrettyJsonModule` that you import. One component cannot be declared in two modules and that what the error reports.

To fix just remove `PrettyJsonComponent` from `configureTestingModule` declarations.