# Error While Building ionic 3 project AoT issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic. I have created new application using the ionic framework. But when I hit command `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` build failed with AOT exception..

Everything working fine if I hit command `ionic build`.

> **Error Message:**

---

[image]

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)