# Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules: AppModule

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to build Basic Ionic SideMenu with following below link
https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-side-menu-tab-bars/ and when i try to build i am getting exception like **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DashboardTabsPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DashboardTabsPageModule! Please consider moving DashboardTabsPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and DashboardTabsPageModule**

### app.module.ts:

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { DashboardTabsPage } from '../pages/dashboard-tabs/dashboard-tabs';
import { ListsTabsPage } from '../pages/lists-tabs/lists-tabs';
import { NoTabsPage } from '../pages/no-tabs/no-tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DashboardTabsPage,
    ListsTabsPage,
    NoTabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DashboardTabsPage,
    ListsTabsPage,
    NoTabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### app.component.ts:

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

### Home.ts:

```
import { DashboardTabsPage } from '../dashboard-tabs/dashboard-tabs';
import { ListsTabsPage } from '../lists-tabs/lists-tabs';
import { NoTabsPage } from '../no-tabs/no-tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
  rootPage = 'DashboardTabsPage';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardTabsPage },
      { title: 'My Lists', component: ListsTabsPage },
      { title: 'Direkt Profile Link', component: DashboardTabsPage},
      { title: 'No Tabs Link', component: NoTabsPage },
    ];
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component, { openTab: page.openTab });
  }

}
```

### home.ts:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: Did you check your home.module.ts. Remove DashboardTabsPage import if its exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 1):

As the error says  **`"Type DashboardTabsPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DashboardTabsPageModule!"`** you need to export the component **`DashboardTabsPage`** in **`DashboardTabsPageModule`** and import **`DashboardTabsPageModule`** under imports of app.module.ts.

Since you dont have **`DashboardTabsPage`** module, you just remove those from the app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    // DashboardTabsPage,
    // ListsTabsPage,
    // NoTabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ]
```

Comment: can you post your DashboardTabsPageModule

Comment: actually i don't have DashboardTabsPageModule  name class

Comment: if you dont have the module, remove the related components

Comment: now i am getting Component DashboardTabsPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: dude you're not sure what you are doing, then definitely you have DashboardTabsPage somewhere

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't include such entities to multiple modules. The proper way will be to import it to `DashboardTabsPageModule` and import this module to `AppModule`. Don't include it to both at the same time.

Comment: same answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
**
import { NoTabsPage } from '../pages/no-tabs/no-tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    // DashboardTabsPage,
    // ListsTabsPage,
    // NoTabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
**
```

comment out the geneated ionic page declarations

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import of DashboardTabsPage from app.module.ts. Cause it is already being imported in home.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 pages:

1. ChatPage
2. ChatGroupPage

I deleted the module of `chatGroupPage.ts` and in the `chatModule.ts` I include the `ChatGroupPage` in declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ChatPage, ChatGroupPage],
  entryComponents:[ChatGroupPage]
})
```

Is working :-)