# AdminModule and AppModule! Please consider moving SignUpComponent to a higher module that imports AdminModule and AppModule

Tags: angular

compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Type SignUpComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AdminModule and AppModule! Please consider moving SignUpComponent to a higher module that imports AdminModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes SignUpComponent then import that NgModule in AdminModule and AppModule.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (compiler.js:10751)
    at compiler.js:10651
    at Array.forEach ()
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10642)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:24566)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24547)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:24507)
    at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_NGCC__ (core.js:14507)

Comment: Welcome! Please read again our guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask a question which can be answered! You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955873/component-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-in-angular)

Comment: Also [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 0):

A component cannot be declared in two modules : if you need it in 2 modules 1 of them must be included in the other one.