# Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a component called **commonmod.component.ts** that I am including in two other modules (abc and def).

**abc.module.ts**

```
import { commonmod } from '../commonmod/commonmod.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    commonmod
  ]
})
```

**def.module.ts**

```
import { commonmod } from '../commonmod/commonmod.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    commonmod
  ]
})
```

When I redirect one page in abc module to another page in def module, it is throwing me following error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type commonmod is part of the declarations of 2 modules: abcand def! Please consider moving commonmod to a higher module that imports abc and def. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes commonmodthen import that NgModule in abcand def.
>   Error: Type commonmod is part of the declarations of 2 modules: abc and def! Please consider moving commonmodto a higher module that imports abcand def. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes commonmod then import that NgModule in abc and def.

Comment: have you exported the ``commonmod `` component in your module ? if yes then you don't have to add ``commonmod `` to your ``declartions[]`` of other modules.

Comment: But I have to add in import of other modules right?

Comment: you don't have (add component in ``declarations[]``) to as that component has been declared in its module but you have to import that module and add it ti ``imports[]``

Comment: This is the scenario. I have dashboard module(Main Module), employer module, employer module. I have created salary.component.ts. I want to use this component in both of this module.

Comment: where is salary.component.ts declared ? i mean which module ? If it is declared in employer module then add the ``SalaryComponent`` to ``exports[]`` inside ``@NgModule({})`` and then add the employer module to ``imports[]`` of the other module where you want to use the ``SalaryComponent``

Comment: See also [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A component can be declared in one and only one module. If you try to declare it in more than one modules you'll get this error

> Error: Type ... is part of the declarations of 2 (or more) modules:

The solution to this problem is pretty simple. If you need to use a component in more than one modules then add it to the **exports** array of the module that **declared** it.

So lets say we have a component named **GreetingsComponent** thats is declared in a module **TestModule** and I want to use it in **AppComponent** that is declared in **AppModule**. I'll simply add it in the **exports** array of the **TestModule** like this

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {GreetingComponent} from './greeting.component';
@NgModule({
declarations:[GreetingComponent],
exports:[GreetingComponent]
})
export class TestModule
{
}
```

Now as **AppModule** has **imported** **TestModule** and this way all constructs whether **Components, Directive, Pipes etc** that are in the **exports array** of the **TestModule** shall be automatically available to the AppModule.

AppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {TestModule} from './test.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, TestModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can simply use GreetingsComponent  in the AppComponent

```
  <greetings></greetings>
```

A working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glkfsh) here.

Cheers.

Comment: I understand that this works, but i'm missing something, isn't the whole idea of modules is to load only the components needed ? In this case eventually we will always put all components in the app module ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to import it in the top-level AppModule (although you can); you can just import it in just those modules that need it. This particular answer just happens to import TestModule into AppModule, but it could just as well have been imported into ProfileModule or so.

Answer (score 24):

You can't declare a component in more than 1 module.
If both modules need it, you need to declare/export your component in a third module and imports this one in abc & def.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ MainModule ]
})
export class AbcModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ MainModule ]
})
export class DefModule { }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CommonMod ],
  exports:    [ CommonMod ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Answer (score 4):

This may also occur if you are using HMR (Hot Module Replacement) with Angular 9+. The Angular team is working on it.

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35265) for more details and updates.