# Type page is part of the declarations of 2 modules error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to use the same modal in several pages. But I get this error that the type of page is part of the declarations of 2 modules. I know a similar question is already existing ([Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955873/component-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-in-angular)) But I can't get it work with it, since I am not working with a module but with a page.

page.module.ts that is used as model

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';

import { FilterPage } from './filter.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FilterPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: [FilterPage],
  exports:  [FilterPage]
})
export class FilterPageModule {}
```

one of the two page.module.ts used as where the model shall appear

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FilterPage } from '../filter/filter.page'

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { FriendsPage } from './friends.page';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FriendsPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),

  ],
  declarations: [FriendsPage, FilterPage],
  entryComponents:  [FilterPage]
})
export class FriendsPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a folder named shared or whatever you wish.Move your `pipes`, `directives`, `components` and `modals` you want to use multiple times inside the `shared` folder.Then create a `shared.module.ts` inside this folder.
Your setup should be as below.

```
const COMPONENTS=[
FilterPage
];

@NgModule({
    exports:[...COMPONENTS,...PIPES,...DIRECTIVES],
    declarations:[...COMPONENTS,...PIPES,...DIRECTIVES],
    entryComponents:[...COMPONENTS]
})
export class SharedModule{

}
```

then import `SharedModule` to the module you want to use inside.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [FriendsPage],
  entryComponents:  [FriendsPage]
})
export class FriendsPageModule {}
```