# Ionic/Angular Imported Component overwrites the page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-components

I have an IONIC-Angular App, where I use the same Header (div with image, my custom element) in two Tabs - Tab1 & Tab3. The problem is overwriting the content. I see only my header html code, nothing from tab1 and tab 3 html.

```
tab1.html | tab2.html    // Html content inside is different, "frame" below is the same

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

<app-header></app-header>

  <div class="cards">
    Here should be content, displayed below my Header
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Here is **tab1.module.ts** - where I import my HeaderModule (header component is declared there) - as You can guess - Tab3 module is almost the same

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { HeaderModule } from '../header/header.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    HeaderModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [
    Tab1Page,
  ],
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

**header.component.html** - it's my HTML below, which is displayed in Tab1, but below it - I have no content, which I had before in tab1.html like described above: " Here should be content, displayed below my Header "

```
<div class="image-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <span class="helper"></span>
      <img [src]="clubLogo">
  </div>
  <h3>{{ clubName }}</h3>
</div>
<ion-button class="login-button" fill="clear" (click)="onOpenMenu()">
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="log-in"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>

  <ion-button class="info-button" fill="clear" (click)="onOpenMenu()">
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="filter-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
```

**header.module.ts** - here I declare and export my Component in order to use it 2 times in my app (more in the future) - as it was recommended here:

> [Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955873/component-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-in-angular/53955978)

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations:[HeaderComponent],
  exports:[HeaderComponent]
})
export class HeaderModule
{
}
```

During describing the problem I was thinking of reversing idea - to put my header as a main conent and create Tab1 and Tab3 content as the two separated components.

But it's a temporary solution... I would be glad to know how to use component, when I want to use it more than one time. Thank You so much for any answers!

[IMG: What I am trying to do is marked on red - current Tab1 displaying. Using  doesn't help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0rIP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 
`<ion-header> (...) </ion-header>`
tag to show up a header into your app. Then use `<ion-content> (...) </ion-content>`  to display content.

If you're beginning on Ionic, I suggest you not to use one component for theses pages. You'll may change your title or something else in the future.

Have you seen the tabs skeleton from Ionic-CLI ? It uses tabs and header as best practices.

```
<ion-header> (your header content here) </ion-header>
<ion-content> (your main content here) </ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for  quick answer. I've tried it and it didn't work... This is not about a standard <ion-header> - I wanted to use some image at the top - without using toolbar and headers.

Comment: I am using Tabs from IONIC-CLI. One component would be helpful, because I want to put there two icons, with the same behavior everywhere as well. Maybe You have some recommendations?