# Angular Error: "is part of the declarations of 2 modules (same)"

Tags: angular

Today a very strange error occured:

> Uncaught Error: Type DashboardComponent is part of the declarations of
>   2 modules: DashboardModule and DashboardModule!

That doesn't make any sense to me. There is only one module called DashboardModule and the DashboardComponent is declared and exported only once in this module.

*Update

Here is how the DashboardModule looks like

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";

import { TypeaheadModule } from "root/shared/typeahead/typeahead.module";
import { AppFormsModule } from "root/shared/forms/forms.module";

import { DynamicComponentService } from "./dynamicComponent.service";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";
import { DashboardWidgetComponent } from "./widget.component";
import { ModalConfigComponent } from "./modalConfig.component";

import { DashboardService } from "./dashboard.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule,
        TranslateModule,
        TypeaheadModule,
        AppFormsModule],
    exports: [
        DashboardComponent,
        DashboardWidgetComponent,
        ModalConfigComponent],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        DashboardWidgetComponent,
        ModalConfigComponent],
    providers: [
        DynamicComponentService,
        DashboardService],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalConfigComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found the bug:

It was Visual Studio code that decided to import the DashobardModule in a new style. Instead of

```
import { DashboardModule } from "root/shared/dashboard/dashboard.module";
```

it started to generate this code

```
import { DashboardModule } from "root/shared/dashboard/dashboard.module.js";
```

On other parts of the code the old way still existed. So, angular thought there would exist two different DashboardModules and brought up the error above. Turns out Angular behaves totally correct but I have to find out why VS Code started to generate such a horrible mess...

Comment: Have you figured how to stop VS Code from doing that

Comment: It is super annoying. I turned off auto JS imports, but it still imports TS modules with .js extension from time to time

Comment: exactly! It doesn’t always add the .js extension but I couldn’t figure out the pattern in which it does.