# declarations of 2 modules error in angular7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-module

I'm trying to run my project, there is just one component, I added home to app.module but its ginvg me this error

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type HomePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and HomePageModule! Please consider moving HomePage to a higher module that imports AppModule and HomePageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomePage then import that NgModule in AppModule and HomePageModule.
Error: Type HomePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and HomePageModule! Please consider moving HomePage to a higher module that imports AppModule and HomePageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomePage then import that NgModule in AppModule and HomePageModule.
here's my app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HomePage} from './home/home.page';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,HomePage],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,RouterModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: PS. MY HOME FOLDER THERE'S ALSO A MODULE:import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}

Comment: is there another module called homepage module

Comment: yes there is and its inside the home folder(home component)

Comment: ok do you want to use lazy load or do you just want to use it

Comment: if you just want to use it remove declarations:[homepage] from HomepageModule it should do fine as y0u have declared it in the appmodules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `HomePage` from `declarations`

change to `declarations: [AppComponent],` in `AppModule`

If you want to use HomePage in route you can configure

```
{    
      path: 'homepage',
      loadChildren: './homepage/homepage.module#HomePageModule'
 },
```

Comment: great.where do I put this? actualy before I added Homepage in declarations it was giving me another error, as I put on the comment bellow my post I have 2 modules One inside the folder home and the actual app.module, I ould like to declare it just on app.module ,I think is the right way

Comment: You need declare in only HomePageModule, if you want use HomePage component as route can put to Routes

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following Remove the `declarations: [HomePage]` from the Homepage Module. if you are not lazy loading

or

you could Either keep it there in the homepage module and remove 
Homepage it from app modules `declarations: [AppComponent,HomePage],`
if you are lazy loading

or if you want to just modularize it
you could Either keep it there in the homepage module and remove 
Homepage it from app modules `declarations: [AppComponent,HomePage],`and add it to `exports:[HomePage]` in home page Module and import The homepage module to appmodule`

```
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,RouterModule],HomePageModule,...
```

Comment: does it contain @NgModule() declration