# Share data between pages - Error - Error: Type HomePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules:

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I'am getting the below error when I try to add Homepage to declarations and entryComponents of `app.module.ts` of the application.

> Error: Type HomePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Comment: Show the app.module file

Comment: This may is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare on component only in one module,
Check if you already declared it on another module.
You can solve it by creating  "sharedModule", declare and export all the shared components on it then import this module were you need it.

Comment: here is the app.module.ts