# Error: Type Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am calling a component in the HTML of a page in ionic , so i added the component to the declarations array of the page.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    DeleteFriendsPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [DeleteFriendsPage,CommunityCardAccordionComponent,GroupTabsComponent],
  entryComponents:  []
})
export class DeleteFriendsPageModule {}
```

i got this error :

> Error: Type CommunityCardAccordionComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: CommunityPageModule and DeleteFriendsPageModule! Please consider moving CommunityCardAccordionComponent to a higher module that imports CommunityPageModule and DeleteFriendsPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes CommunityCardAccordionComponent then import that NgModule in CommunityPageModule and DeleteFriendsPageModul

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules

Comment: already tried this solution! it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598311/component-is-part-of-the-declaration-of-2-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as the error says

> CommunityCardAccordionComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules

In simple terms, you cannot declare a component in more than one module...

On the other hand you can import the same module more than once! So your solution is to simply use modules, follow this steps

1. Remove `CommunityCardAccordionComponent` from **BOTH** `CommunityPageModule and DeleteFriendsPageModule`
2. Inside your **path/to/community-card-accordion-component/**, create a module **CommunityCardAccordionModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [CommunityCardAccordionComponent]
})
export class CommunityCardAccordionModule { }
```

3. Import `CommunityCardAccordionModule`  in both `CommunityPageModule and DeleteFriendsPageModule`

Thats it, you solve the issue, now `CommunityCardAccordionComponent` is only declared in one module